# Python Pandas: any ideas on text extraction?

Tags: pandas, text, extract, separator

I have thousands of txt files like the following (the values are made up):

```
Date :  [ 2010-01-01 XX:XX:XX ]  Age :  [ 22 ]  Sex :  [ M ]   :  [ XXX ]
Height(cm) :  [ 145 ]  Weight(kg) :  [ 56.4 ]  Race :  [ Hispanic ]
Spirometry :  [ restrictive pattern ]
Treatment response :  [ Negative ]
Tissue volume :  [ Normal ]
Tissue volume
[ Normal RV ] 
Diffusing capacity :  [ Normal capacity ]
FVC Liters : [ 2.22 ] FVC Liters :  [ 67 ] FVC Liters :  [ 3.35 ] 
FEV1 Liters :  [ 1.96 ] FEV1 Liters :  [ 66 ] FEV1 Liters :  [ 2.06 ] 
FEV1 / FVC % :  [ 58 ] FEV1 / FVC % :  [ 62 ]
DLCO mL/mmHg/min :  [ 21.5 ] DLCO mL/mmHg/min :  [ 102 ]
DLCO Adj mL/mmHg/min :  [ 21.5 ] DLCO Adj mL/mmHg/min :  [ 102 ]
RV/TLC % :  [ 22 ]
```

I want to extract variable names and their corresponding values in a csv format. Luckily, as you have noticed, all txt files have similar format as such:

```
variable : [ value ]
```

1. My first problem is how to write a code that extract data with the above structure.
2. My second problem is that I do now know how to separate when there are multiple sets of "variable : [value]" in a single line.(They are not comma separated!).

I've only managed to come up with the following code...but I am going in circles now. Any ideas?

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep='\n')
df = df[0].str.split(':', expand=True)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need regular expressions. Let's try this

First, load sample data

```
text = \
"""Date :  [ 2010-01-01 XX:XX:XX ]  Age :  [ 22 ]  Sex :  [ M ]   :  [ XXX ]
Height(cm) :  [ 145 ]  Weight(kg) :  [ 56.4 ]  Race :  [ Hispanic ]
Spirometry :  [ restrictive pattern ]
Treatment response :  [ Negative ]
Tissue volume :  [ Normal ]
Tissue volume
[ Normal RV ] 
Diffusing capacity :  [ Normal capacity ]
FVC Liters : [ 2.22 ] FVC Liters :  [ 67 ] FVC Liters :  [ 3.35 ] 
FEV1 Liters :  [ 1.96 ] FEV1 Liters :  [ 66 ] FEV1 Liters :  [ 2.06 ] 
FEV1 / FVC % :  [ 58 ] FEV1 / FVC % :  [ 62 ]
DLCO mL/mmHg/min :  [ 21.5 ] DLCO mL/mmHg/min :  [ 102 ]
DLCO Adj mL/mmHg/min :  [ 21.5 ] DLCO Adj mL/mmHg/min :  [ 102 ]
RV/TLC % :  [ 22 ]
"""
```

Next, use a regex to find all matching 'blah : [ blahblah ] ' pairs, and stick into a dictionary (`strip`ed from white space -- could have gone into a regex but to avoid over-complicating things)

```
import re
parsed = re.findall('(.*?)\:\s*?\[(.*?)\]',text)
res = {g[0].strip() : g[1].strip() for g in parsed}
res
```

The result:

```
{'Date': '2010-01-01 XX:XX:XX',
 'Age': '22',
 'Sex': 'M',
 '': 'XXX',
 'Height(cm)': '145',
 'Weight(kg)': '56.4',
 'Race': 'Hispanic',
 'Spirometry': 'restrictive pattern',
 'Treatment response': 'Negative',
 'Tissue volume': 'Normal',
 'Diffusing capacity': 'Normal capacity',
 'FVC Liters': '3.35',
 'FEV1 Liters': '2.06',
 'FEV1 / FVC %': '62',
 'DLCO mL/mmHg/min': '102',
 'DLCO Adj mL/mmHg/min': '102',
 'RV/TLC %': '22'}
```

You can stick it into a dataframe if you want:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records([res])
df
```

to get

```
    Date                   Age  Sex           Height(cm)    Weight(kg)  Race      Spirometry           Treatment response    Tissue volume    Diffusing capacity      FVC Liters    FEV1 Liters    FEV1 / FVC %    DLCO mL/mmHg/min    DLCO Adj mL/mmHg/min    RV/TLC %
--  -------------------  -----  -----  ---  ------------  ------------  --------  -------------------  --------------------  ---------------  --------------------  ------------  -------------  --------------  ------------------  ----------------------  ----------
 0  2010-01-01 XX:XX:XX     22  M      XXX           145          56.4  Hispanic  restrictive pattern  Negative              Normal           Normal capacity               3.35           2.06              62                 102                     102          22
```

Note that the sample you provided has this line towards the top  `Sex :  [ M ]   :  [ XXX ]` which does not fit the pattern but the code deals with it by using an empty string '' as the key. I assume this is an issue with copy-paste rather than an issue in the original data, but if you have many of these you may have to handle them more carefully

Comment: Thanks for the detailed guidance! I had no idea what regular expression was before. I'll try out your solution

Answer (score 0):

For the example data, to get the keys and the values without the leading and trailing spaces you can use 2 capture groups.

```
([^\s:][^:]*)\s+\:\s+\[\s*([^][]*)\s+]
```

- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[^\s:][^:]*` Match any char except a whitespace char or `:` followed by optional chars other than `:`
- `)` Close group 1
- `\s+\:\s+` Match `:` between 1 or more whitespace chars at the left and right
- `\[\s*` Match `[` and optional whitespace chars
- `(` Capture **group 2**

  - `[^][]*` Match 0+ times any char except `[` and `]`
- `)` Close group 2
- `\s+] Match 1+ whitespace chars and` ]`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/j5i28n/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/97APdU)

Output

```
[('Date', '2010-01-01 XX:XX:XX'), ('Age', '22'), ('Sex', 'M'), ('Height(cm)', '145'), ('Weight(kg)', '56.4'), ('Race', 'Hispanic'), ('Spirometry', 'restrictive pattern'), ('Treatment response', 'Negative'), ('Tissue volume', 'Normal'), ('Diffusing capacity', 'Normal capacity'), ('FVC Liters', '2.22'), ('FVC Liters', '67'), ('FVC Liters', '3.35'), ('FEV1 Liters', '1.96'), ('FEV1 Liters', '66'), ('FEV1 Liters', '2.06'), ('FEV1 / FVC %', '58'), ('FEV1 / FVC %', '62'), ('DLCO mL/mmHg/min', '21.5'), ('DLCO mL/mmHg/min', '102'), ('DLCO Adj mL/mmHg/min', '21.5'), ('DLCO Adj mL/mmHg/min', '102'), ('RV/TLC %', '22')]
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea! I'll dig dipper into regular expression